# Check what is the name of the POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

When I click a button, it is handled by ajax and then post to a PHP page. current problem is the PHP cannot recognize the POST name from the front end. It keep throwing me the else part whichis "NOT OK". Below are the snippet.

**PHP part**

```
if (isset($_POST['btn-agree'])){  echo "OK<br />"; } else {  echo "NOT OK<br />"; }
```

**END PHP part**

```js
$(function() {
$("#btn-agree").click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "postAgreement.php",
    success: function(msg){
        //do something
    },
    error: function(){
       //do something
    }
});
});
});
```

```html
<form id="agree-form" action="/" method="post" role="form">
<input type="submit" name="btn-agree" id="btn-agree" value="Agree">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not specifying the data to be sent to the server. Use the `data` parameter and [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) the form.

```
$(function() {
$("#btn-agree").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "postAgreement.php",
    data: $('#agree-form').serialize(),
    success: function(msg){
        //do something
    },
    error: function(){
       //do something
    }
});
});
});
```

**EDIT:** It looks like `.serialize()` does not include the `submit` input type. To test the request method to the script, you can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` and test that it equals `"POST"`. You can also set the `data` parameter to `"btn-agree=Agree"`.

Comment: in the postAgreement.php, I receive it as POST that is ok?

Comment: Yes, it will be received as POST.

Comment: But it is still not working after  Iadd the data part. It is still showing 'NOT OK'.. is it maybe the <form action="/"> ?

Comment: Looks like using .serialize() will not include the submit type. If you are testing that the script is being accessed via POST, you can check that `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST"`.

Comment: You can also set the `data` parameter to `"btn-agree=Agree"`.

Comment: $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] return POST, which is ok. The only part is that PHP did not recognize btn-agree which is weird... because in the HTML page I will include many button, all these buttons will link to ONE PHP page, I need to code the PHP page to specifically run the function according to which button pressed...

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the parameter "data" on your ajax.
on isset($_POST['btn-agree']) will always be false because the $_POST['btn-agree'] is not define or set.

check this code or see sample on http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/:

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: { btn-agree: $('#btn-agree').val() },
    url: "postAgreement.php",
    success: function(msg){
        //do something
    },
    error: function(){
       //do something
    }
});